# Closed form for the function $G(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (e^{x/n²}-1) $

Tags: analysis, summation, summation-method

Consider the following function :

$$G(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (e^{x/n²}-1)$$

I know that the sum converges .

Also ,$$G(x) =(1/2π) \int_{-π}^{π} f(xe^{-it})e^{e^{it}} dt$$

Where,
 $f(x)= π\sqrt{x}cot(π\sqrt{x}) -1$

> > Question : Can a closed form possible for this function (other than mentioned above)?

Comment: It's pretty tricky looking... Any background on where it came from or what it means so we can consider other strategies?

Comment: I think you can write it like 
$$
G(x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^k \zeta(2k)}{k!}
$$

Comment: Looks like the integral is the generating transform from here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function_transformation#Integral_transformations

Looks like you are trying to find the exponential generating function for $\zeta(2k)$ from the O.G.F. So I think your $f(x) = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{\pi}{2} \sqrt{x} \cot(\pi \sqrt{x})$

Comment: @BenedictW.J.Irwin  thank you for the comments but unfortunately I know all of the above . I'm looking for new form for the function .

Answer (score 3):

So writing
$$
e^{\frac{x}{n^2}} -1 = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(x/n^2)^k}{k!}
$$
we can write 
$$
G(x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^k}{n^{2k}k!}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\zeta(2k)x^k}{k!}
$$

Just some deeper thoughts here will update as I go. Consider
$$
\zeta(2k) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(2k)}\int_0^\infty \frac{t^{2k-1}}{e^t-1} \; dt
$$
then 
$$
G(x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^k}{\Gamma(k+1)\Gamma(2k)}\int_0^\infty \frac{t^{2k-1}}{e^t-1} \; dx
$$
and possibly by exchanging the integral and sum 
$$
G(x) = \int_0^\infty t x \frac{_0F_2(;\frac{3}{2},2;\frac{t^2 x}{4})}{e^t-1} \;dt
$$

**Idea 2**

According to [OEIS A002432](https://oeis.org/A002432)
$$
\zeta(2n) = (-1)^{n-1} B_{2n} 2^{2n-1} \frac{\pi^{2n}}{(2n)!}
$$
so 
$$
G(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} B_{2n} 2^{2n-1} \frac{\pi^{2n} x^n}{(2n)! n!}
$$
$$
H(x) = \frac{G(x)}{2 \pi^2 x} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k!} B_{2k+2} \frac{(2\pi)^{2k} x^{k}}{\Gamma(2k+3)(k+1)}
$$
then according to [Ramanujan Master Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%27s_master_theorem) the Mellin transform of $H(x)$ can be written
$$
\mathcal{M}[H](s) = \Gamma(s)B_{2-2s} \frac{(2\pi)^{-2s} }{\Gamma(3-2s)(1-s)}
$$
my next thoughts would be to substitute the [analytic continuation for the Bernoulli numbers](https://arxiv.org/pdf/physics/9705021.pdf) and see if an inverse Mellin transform or sum over residues makes any sense here to get back to the function...

Comment: Thank you for the answer I'll consider it.

Comment: @Bambi I didn't realise how mind blowing that analytic continuation paper was. I've just got to the particle scattering bit. But yeah, it's unlikely to go anywhere nice after this